# Error with php field validation

Tags: php, html

I have a form on a PHP page which adds a contact into a MySQL table.

But my validation refuses to work. I have edited it a few times but when I click **Add New Contact** button, it adds them even if some fields are empty.

I am still getting the grasp of PHP, but I am sure my mistake is missing something simple.

```
<?php
// Don't post the form until the submit button is pressed.
$requiredFields = array (
        "name",
        "email",
        "extension",
        "extension" 
); // Add the 'name' for all required fields to this array
$errors = false;
if (isset ( $_POST ['Submit'] )) {
    // Clean all inputs
    array_walk ( $_POST, 'check_input' );

    // Loop over requiredFields and output error if any are empty
    foreach ( $requiredFields as $r ) {
        if (strlen ( $_POST [$r] ) == 0) {
            $errors = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Error/success check
    if ($errors == true) {
        echo 'Fields marked with a * are required';
    } else {
        // no errors
        // ...
    }
}

// check_input function
function check_input(&$data) {
    $data = trim ( $data );
    $data = stripslashes ( $data );
    $data = htmlspecialchars ( $data, ENT_QUOTES );
    return $data;
}
?>
<h2>Add Contact</h2>
<form name="form1" action="&lt;?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?&gt;?mode=added"
    method="post">
    <table class="tableStyleClassTwo">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" />
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Extension:</td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <input type="text" name="extension" />
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Department:</td>
            <td><select name="department">
                    <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
                    <option value="AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR">AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR</option>
                    <option value="ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL">ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL</option>
                    <option value="AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)">AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)</option>
                    <option value="BANDIT-VW">BANDIT-VW</option>
                    <option value="BOOKINGS VW">BOOKINGS VW</option>
                    <option value="DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS">DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS</option>
                    <option value="FINANCE AND INSURANCE">FINANCE AND INSURANCE</option>
                    <option value="IT DEPARTMENT">IT DEPARTMENT</option>
                    <option value="MARKETING DEPARTMENT">MARKETING DEPARTMENT</option>
                    <option value="MASTER CARS">MASTER CARS</option>
                    <option value="MAYOR OF PINETOWN">MAYOR OF PINETOWN</option>
                    <option value="NEW CAR PREP DEPARTMENT">NEW CAR PREP DEPARMENT</option>
                    <option value="NUMBER PLATES">NUMBER PLATES</option>
                    <option value="PANELBEATER - EASIFIX - CAR CARE">PANELBEATER - EASIFIX - CAR CARE</option>
                    <option value="PARTS">PARTS</option>
                    <option value="PARTS DISPATCH">PARTS DISPATCH</option>
                    <option value="PARTS TELESALES">PARTS TELLESALES</option>
                    <option value="USED CAR PREP AND ORDERS">USED CAR PREP AND ORDERS</option>
                    <option value="VW NEW CARS ADMIN AND STOCK CONTROL">VW NEW CARS ADMIN AND STOCK CONTROL</option>
                    <option value="VW NEW VEHICLE SHOWROOM">VW NEW VEHICLE SHOWROOM</option>
                    <option value="VW SERVICE ADVISORS">VW SERVICE ADVISORS</option>
                    <option value="VW WORKSHOP">VW WORKSHOP</option>
                    <option value="VW WORKSHOP FOREMEN">VW WORKSHOP FOREMEN</option>
                    <option value="WARRANTY &amp; CLAIMS">WARRANTY & CLAIMS</option>
                    <option value="WORKSHOP DRIVERS">WORKSHOP DRIVERS</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="centre"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a>
                | <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Add New Contact" <?php if($disable ==1){?> disabled <?php } ?> />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="added">
    </table>
</form>
<?php
break;
//added a record
case 'added':
//first setup the vars
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$extension = $_POST['extension'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
//then lets use'em
$sql = "INSERT INTO address (name, phone, email, extension, department) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $phone . "','" . $email . "','" . $extension . "','" . $department . "')";
//echo $sql;
//return;
mysql_query($sql);
//done take me back to the main page
header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
break;
```

Comment: getting blank page? its working fine on my side: getting this `Fields marked with a * are required`

Comment: Side note, if the value of the options is the same as what is between the tags, you don't need to put the value. It defaults to what's between the tags so `<option value="AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR">AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR</option>` is the same as `<option>AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR</option>`

Comment: @devpro for me it still adds it to the table with the empty fields.

Comment: @devpro let me try something one sec.

Comment: you are inserting data in ELSE condition??? right

Comment: i edited my code @devpro have a look at the bottom its some code i forgot to post.

Comment: your query must be inside the ELSE condition of  `if ($errors == true) {`

Comment: did u checked it?

Comment: anyone checked **$requiredFields** array => **department**  field is not there for validate but instead  of that  TWO TIMES **extension**  field is there , can we guess it cause the problem.?

Comment: @SoniVimal: no this is not an issue, OP said, data insert as empty in table.

Comment: @devpro sorry was busy with work I am going to try now :)

Comment: alright, do it.

Comment: Thank you @devpro all working :D

Comment: glad to help u ..